# How does the solve() function produce factor correlation scores in the factanal() function?

Tags: r, factor-analysis, factor-rotation

Using the factanal() function in R produces factor correlations:

```
> set.seed(500)
> tmp = cbind(rnorm(200,2,1.5),rnorm(200,2,1.5),rnorm(200,2,1.5),rnorm(200,2,1.5),rnorm(200,2,1.5),rnorm(200,2,1.5))
> print(factanal(tmp, 3, rotation="promax"))

Call:
factanal(x = tmp, factors = 3, rotation = "promax")

Uniquenesses:
[1] 0.796 0.889 0.966 0.935 0.740 0.005

Loadings:
     Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
[1,]                  0.441 
[2,]          0.311  -0.114 
[3,]                  0.139 
[4,]                  0.258 
[5,]          0.495         
[6,]  0.999                 

               Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
SS loadings      1.010   0.353   0.300
Proportion Var   0.168   0.059   0.050
Cumulative Var   0.168   0.227   0.277

Factor Correlations:
        Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
Factor1   1.000  -0.128   0.117
Factor2  -0.128   1.000   0.118
Factor3   0.117   0.118   1.000

The degrees of freedom for the model is 0 and the fit was 8e-04
```

After some digging, I found the following code produces the factor correlations:

```
tmat <- solve(tmp$rotmat)
 R <- tmat %*% t(tmat)
```

Could someone please explain to me how the solve() function using the rotation matrix produces factor correlation scores? And why this results in different factor correlations compared to directly correlating factor scores?

Comment: Factor scores can be estimated using a number of different approaches (e.g., regression or Bartlett) so there will even be variability in factor correlations based on factor scores.